# Cannot display image in vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm saving image in following path :

```
storage\app\public\img\user_image
```

and saving image url like this in database:

```
/img/user_image/285070719.png
```

trying to display image like this:

```
 <img :src="'../app/public'+profile.image">
```

but the image does not display, Any solution to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `'../app/public'+` part maybe, `/public/` should not appear in an URL, it should be the "root" of your project/webserver. The image should be available via its url: `/img/user_image/285070719.png`

Comment: check console or network tab on the browser?

Comment: @dılosürücü: No there is no error.

Comment: @kerbh0lz: I have tried removing public but facing same issue

Comment: Entering `http://localhost:8000/img/user_image/285070719.png` in your browser should show the image (supposed http://localhost:8000 is your project root). Does the _file_ exist?

Comment: @kerbh0lz: yes file exist, but i have checked this url by directly entering in the browser, but no image is shown

Comment: Did you create the symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` with `php artisan storage:link`? The path to your image should be `storage/img/user_image/285070719.png`, so something like `<img :src="'/storage'+profile.image">`

Comment: @Remul: I have created symlink but same issue

Comment: @user3653474 You cannot open the image manually in the browser with `http://localhost:8000/storage/img/user_image/285070719.png`?

Comment: @Remul: Yes i'm getting image

Comment: @user3653474 Ok then check the URL  that is generated when you use `<img :src="'/storage'+profile.image">` and tweak it so it generates the correct one.

Comment: @Remul: Thanks now it is working, i was not putting storage in the url

Answer (score 0):

Have you create a storage link? `php artisan storage:link` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Then you should be able to use the uri like `/storgae/img/user_image/285070719.png`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you created the symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` with `php artisan storage:link`, after that make sure that the generated URL is correct.

The following URL should be generated:

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/img/user_image/285070719.png
```

Something like the following should work for you:

```
<img :src="'/storage'+profile.image">
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk):

The `public` disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the `public` disk uses the `local` driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`. To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command: `php artisan storage:link`